# Am I the only one finding it confusing to move back and forth between meta and main website?

Tags: discussion, design

If you in meta, there's no clear button to take you back to the main website, same thing when you in the website and you want to go to meta.
Meta theme is also so similar to the main website that I sometimes get confused between them.

Comment: This was among the biggest complaints in the original post announcing the change - hiding meta under the dropdown(s) won't promote participation in meta.  Numerous userscripts and userstyles have popped up to fix shortcomings of the new topbar - [including the main/meta links](https://github.com/Undo1/SE-Topbar-MainMeta/blob/7d0cb1a38b4fb21951236a0be55702c24614adbb/script.user.js) (Click "Raw" to install if you have Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.  That revision linked because the most recent is a broken merge.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There used to be a link to Meta in the navigation bar, but it was removed recently. Now, you'll have to expand the StackExchange dropdown to move between Meta and main:

[image]

It's not immediately obvious where the links are, but once you find them I think. it's pretty easy to switch between the sites. Note that the link to site you are currently on (in my case Meta) is bolded.

Further reading:

- [Feedback request: New top bar and MultiCollider redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign) (on MSO)
- [A New Top Bar for Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/) (on blog.SO)

Comment: Note on the main site the help menu also has a link to meta.